# Is there any way to convert maven projects developed using jdeveloper to normal java project?

Tags: java, maven, jdeveloper

In jdeveloper, i couldn't find any option like configure and convert to maven project like in eclipse. Please guide me to do this.

Comment: What is a normal java project? How do you want to manage your dependencies?

Comment: I want to remove maven dependencies.

Comment: If you don't need some of the dependencies, why not erase them from the pom.xml?

Comment: This might seem like a silly suggestion but if Eclipse gives you the functionality you want, couldnt you use Eclipse to remove the maven project stuff and then import into JDeveloper?